# как перехватить CTRL+C в PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

Подскажите как в PowerShell скрипте можно перехватить нажатие CTRL+C и выполнить после этого что-то другое. Для баша я использую Trap, а вот как такое же сделать в PowerShell не знаю..

Пример реализации в баше:

```
#!/bin/bash
function trapsucsess {

    echo "Действие после CTRL+C"
}

count=0

trap trapsucsess 2

while [ $count -lt 100 ]
do
sleep 1
(( count++ ))
echo $count
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На англоязычном SO есть [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733718/is-there-a-way-to-catch-ctrl-c-and-ask-the-user-to-confirm) которое легко адаптируется под ваши нужды, так же там есть ссылка на обсуждение аналогичного вопроса в MSDN

Comment: другими словами, нужно вставлять обработчик в цикл? а можно все-таки перехватывать какое-нибудь событие?

Comment: ну если имеется в виду некоторая интерактивность работы скрипта то есть возможность перехватить нажатие клавиш в окне консоли

Comment: не обязательно в консоли. просто не хотелось бы размазывать чтение клавиш по всем циклам.